# Migrating Telerik MVC Grid to Kendo UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-ui

I am migrating an AJAX Data-bound Telerik grid to the a Kendo UI grid.

With Telerik the controller method was returning a `PartialViewResult` (using in-house framework function call), but with the new Kendo UI grid, I am only able to make it work by returning a `JsonResult`.
If I return a `PartialViewResult`, the grid renders empty.

**Question:**
Is it possible to return a `PartialViewResult` with a Kendo UI grid?

**Telerik code:**

```
[GridAction]
public PartialViewResult SelectProducts()
{
    return DoChildReadingAction(() => 
        _service.GetAllProducts().ToProductListItemViewModels(), "_ChildError");
}
```

**Kendo UI code:**

```
public JsonResult SelectProducts([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    return Json(_service.GetAllProducts().ToProductListItemViewModels()
                        .ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

Comment: Try opening from the browser the URL serving the data and check the format of the returned JSON or edit the original question including the returned page and we might take a look into it.

Comment: OnaBai, I hope this will answer your question:
ContentEncoding = null
ContentType = null
Data = DataSourceResult with 14 items, Errors is null
JsonRequestBehavior was DenyGet, but I modified to add parameter AllowGet

Then I am feeding this to DoChildReadingAction(), which returns a PartialViewResult with Model containing the JsonResult.

Comment: Actually I was asking for the JSON in order to help you specify how the `DataSource` definition should look like. Seems that you return the array of results in `DataSourceResult` that means that `schema.data` should be `"DataSourceResults"` (see http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#schemadata-functionstring) but not knowing if the JSON arrives to the browser and not seeing neither the code nor the JSON is difficult to figure out why is not being displayed. Is the browser console showing any error?

Comment: With Fiddler I see more clearly, I am getting the "_ChildError" page, it's returning error 500. The JSON is empty. So the problem is in the DoChildReadingAction() function call. Thanks OnaBai.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kendo UI Grid for ASP.NET MVC works **only** with JSON result. It will not work with a PartialResult. More info can be found in the [AJAX binding](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-binding) help topic.

You just need to convert your code:

```
public JsonResult SelectProducts([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    return Json(_service.GetAllProducts().ToProductListItemViewModels()
                        .ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

Also make sure you have included `kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js` to your page. Otherwise you would see `DenyGet` errors. Check the [troubleshooting](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/troubleshooting) help topic for further details.